# Best alternative of Itunes for the use of iPods

Tags: video, music, itunes

I have a large music collection on an external drive, and until I installed ubuntu, my preferred music player was Itunes. I am currently using Rythymbox. Is there a program that is better for listening, loading onto Ipods, and general organization?

Comment: The only solution to get everything working with my iPods is to use windows and iTunes. it's a bit sad but true...

Comment: Agreed , even the best one (gtkpod) has much limitations , and the song list format was incompatible with itunes (and missing the Voice Pack).

Answer (score 7):

It's a question of personal preferences. I use both Rythmbox and Banshee and still don't know which one I like ;)

Comment: I keep wanting one of the two to be clearly better, also.

Answer (score 5):

I find Banshee to be an excellent Media player. It feels less like a utility than Rhythmbox does, however both are quite capable.

Answer (score 3):

There is always Amarok as well ... this, like RythmBox is a fairly heavy, full featured music player. Songbird is always an option as well, but the reviews don't seem to be good.

Comment: Songbird has [dropped support for Linux](http://blog.songbirdnest.com/2010/04/02/songbird-singing-a-new-tune/), but keep an eye on the [planned Linux fork](http://getnightingale.com/) for its reappearance. I'd also like to point out that Amarok is nothing like iTunes in interface or playlist behavior. While I personally could not survive without Amarok, someone who preferred iTunes would definitely not feel at home in it.

Comment: @ændrük though we can hope that Glen will try amarok and possibly like it

Comment: @ændrük of course! I forgot about "the wolf", which was my choice before I switched to Ubuntu. Nice player too, but I don't know about it's iTunes support.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is Banshee, but it's a matter of your preference.

Answer (score 2):

Well linux is all about choices. Although you may have a very hard time exactly replacing itunes if you use ipods as well, in terms of music management there are many choices.

[Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/)

A QT based music player and manager. Available in the repos but may require [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~me-davidsansome/+archive/clementine) installation if you want the latest release.

[image]

Other than this there are:

[Xnoise](http://www.xnoise-media-player.com/)

which can be installed from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~shkn/+archive/xnoise).

[Beatbox](https://launchpad.net/beat-box)

Which is quite new and in heavy development. But can be installed from [ppa](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/elementary-music-player-beatbox-development-release-sneaks-out-in-ppa/).

Answer (score 1):

Try Exaile and Banshee, and search 'music' in the Ubuntu Software Center.  Let us know what you decide on.

Answer (score 1):

Rythmbox has come a long way since I first began looking for an iTune-Alternative.  Since the advent of the Ubuntu One Music store, I've gotten a lot more comfortable with purchasing and saving tracks for use with (yes, I said with) my iTunes library. If I had a non-apple MP3 player, I'd definitely go with Rythmbox.

As is, Rythmbox accurately detects and manages 'most' of my library when connected to my ipod.
You will still have issues with any proprietary tracks, but I've grown fond of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at quodlibet ! -> http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/

It requires a bit of reading to fully see how awesome it is.
I find it to be by far the most practical for large library.
I tried them all, im sticking with this one.

.. but it's a matter of your preference :D

Answer (score 1):

[guayadeque [image: Install guayadeque]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/guayadeque) is really good too!

For more information see [its SourceForge site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guayadeque/) and [main site](http://guayadeque.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's a matter of personal preference. You could run Songbird under WINE if you want to get the closest iTunes feel.

Answer (score 0):

Banshee allows you to save the ratings in the ID3 tags so you don't have to rate again when you move your collection. The only other player I know that's doing this is Songbird. But Songbird is no longer officially supported for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

gtkPod is also an app which I used to add music onto my iPod, but that was during the Karmic release, I have no idea how far Rhythmbox has come since then though.