# iTunes Alternatives for Ubuntu

Tags: windows, music, ipod, itunes

I have started using Ubuntu very recently. I installed using Wubi. Can I get my Windows iTunes Music to go onto Ubuntu's iTunes alternative. Also, how will I sync my iPod with Ubuntu? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best program for listening , loading onto Ipods, and general organization of large music collections?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3880/what-is-the-best-program-for-listening-loading-onto-ipods-and-general-organiz)

Answer (score 2):

Rhythmbox or banshee both are very good and they support ipods and iphones.