# iTunes doesn't run properly

Tags: 11.10, itunes

After installing iTunes I noticed that the layout was not the proper one.

[image]

How can I get iTunes working on Ubuntu?

Comment: Why do you need iTunes on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently and according to WineHQ, iTunes [does not work with Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22451) in a very good manner. Specially after version 7.

What you are seeing is normal and cannot be fixed using current versions of software.

If you want to try out alternatives that run in Ubuntu please visit these questions, there is already plenty of suggestions on the site

- [Best alternative of Itunes for the use of iPods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3880/best-alternative-of-itunes-for-the-use-of-ipods)
- [iTunes Alternatives for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79643/itunes-alternatives-for-ubuntu)

Has an alternative and if you have it available you can use VirtualBox to install Windows and run iTunes from inside the guest system.

Comment: And don't forget if using VirtualBox: It will need some extra user rights for usb support: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB

Comment: @jangroth that my friend is another question for another day ;)

Comment: Hope everything is working as expected or at least close to what you need.